# $_SESSION doesn't update after logged in with $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

$_SESSION  doesn't update after logged in with $.ajax, even after page is refreshed.

All of my pages begin with `<?php session_start(); ?>`

If

```
if( isset($_SESSION['candidat_id'])&& isset($_SESSION['candidat_civilite'])&& isset($_SESSION['candidat_nom'])&& isset($_SESSION['candidat_prenom']))
{echo 'yes';}
else 
{echo 'no';}
```

// Returns 'no' even if json returns "Bienvenue Mme Fleur Deschamps !" in my login modal. Once the modal is closed, the page gets refreshed, so my sessionn should be updated, but it's not the case actually.
Could you kindly tell me what's wrong?
Thanks.

here's my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_login").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({     
            type : 'POST',
            url : "ajx/process_login.php",
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            encode : true
        }).done(function(data) { 
            if ( data.error.bienvenue$) {
                $('#infos_login').empty().append(data.error.bienvenue$); 
                $('#login_mdp_oublie').fadeOut();
            }
// data.error.bienvenue$  returns "Bienvenue Mme Fleur DESCHAMPS"
```

**here's my full process_login.php

```
$error =array();

if ( empty($_POST['email_login']) OR empty($_POST['pass']) )
   { $error['tous_les_champs'] ="Vous devez renseigner<br/>votre email et mot de passe";
   }
else  {  include('../pdo_connect.php'); 
        $email=$_POST['email_login'];
        $password1 =$_POST['pass'];
        $password=md5($password1);

        $query =$marInterim -> prepare('SELECT * FROM marinterim_candidats WHERE candidat_email=:candidat_email AND candidat_password=:candidat_password');
        $query ->bindParam(':candidat_email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query ->bindParam(':candidat_password',$password , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query ->execute();

        $rowCount=$query->rowCount(); 

     if ( $rowCount ==1)
        { $reponse = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

         if (empty($_POST['remember_me']))
            {
                 $_SESSION['candidat_id']= $reponse['candidat_id']; 
                 $_SESSION['candidat_civilite']= $reponse['candidat_civilite']; 
                 $_SESSION['candidat_nom']= strtoupper($reponse['candidat_nom']); 
                 $_SESSION['candidat_prenom']= $reponse['candidat_prenom']; 
                 $_SESSION['candidat_email']= $reponse['candidat_email']; 

                 $error['bienvenue$'] ="Bienvenue ".$_SESSION['candidat_civilite']." ".$_SESSION['candidat_prenom']." ".$_SESSION['candidat_nom']." !" ;
            }
        else{    $_COOKIE['candidat_id']= $reponse['candidat_id'];
                 $_COOKIE['candidat_civilite']= $reponse['candidat_civilite']; 
                 $_COOKIE['candidat_nom']= strtoupper($reponse['candidat_nom']); 
                 $_COOKIE['candidat_prenom']= $reponse['candidat_prenom']; 
                 $_COOKIE['candidat_email']= $reponse['candidat_email']; 

                 setcookie ('candidat_id', $candidat_id, time()+3600*24*360, '/', null, false);
                 setcookie ('candidat_civilite', $candidat_civilite, time()+3600*24*360, '/', null, false);
                 setcookie ('candidat_nom', $candidat_nom, time()+3600*24*360, '/', null, false);
                 setcookie ('candidat_prenom', $candidat_prenom, time()+3600*24*360, '/', null, false);
                 setcookie ('candidat_email', $candidat_email, time()+3600*24*360, '/', null, false);

                 $error['bienvenueC'] ='Bienvenue '.$civc.' '.$prenomc.' '.$nomc.' !' ;                     
            }
        }
else{ $error['inconnu'] ='Désolés, les identifiants fournis ne correspondent à aucun candidat enregistré dans notre base de données.';   
    }
}

$data['error']  = $error;
include('array2json.php');
echo array2json($data);
```

********** Now, my functions on modal close ********

```
$('#close_login').click(function() {
    $('#ctn_modal_login').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000);
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '<?php echo $escaped_link;?>';  }, 3000); 
}); 
// $escaped_link = current page
```

Comment: you forgot session_start() at beginning.

Comment: @Yair.R OP said all of his pages started with session_start()

Comment: damn.. most of the times the answer is that :(

Comment: as it is only "some part" of process_login.php, we cannot know what's up: if $rowCount has a chance to be "1", or if you echo json_encode($error) at the end

Comment: In this case, the user has been found as `$error['bienvenue$'] ="Bienvenue ".$_SESSION['candidat_civilite']." ".$_SESSION['candidat_prenom']." ".$_SESSION['candidat_nom']." !" ;` returns "Bienvenue Mme Fleur Deschamps !". in my loggin modal, once logged in

Comment: `$data['error']  = $error;
include('array2json.php');
echo array2json($data);`

Comment: Did you try without any ajax call ? Did you ensure you have nohting before your session_start() (dirty blankspaces or so) ?

Comment: You forgot the `session_start()` **INSIDE** the ajax file.

Comment: Yes I've checked that there's no space before `<?php session_start() ; ?>` and I've jsut checked without ajax : so result is of course : YES : Session ok...

Comment: Ismael Miguel : You're right ! it works now.. I thought that  processor.php didn't need  session_start ...  Ok, ok... 
Well It was indeed a session_start() matter... Okay thanks and sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

You're sending session id?

Like this:

```
var param1= 'val1';
var sessionID = '<?php echo session_id(); ?>';
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'anyfile.php', 
  data: 'p1=' + param1+ '&sid=' + sessionID
});
```

Comment: Thanks - This topic is solved See our comments. But thanks anyway :)